# Can't find my DVD drive in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, 16.04, hardware, dvd

I guess you could say that I'm a slightly educated noob (I know, a little knowledge is a dangerous thing).

My drive worked fine in Mint 17.3, but I am now running Lubuntu 16.04 and my DVD drive has not worked yet. I have tried multiple CDs and DVDs; music, data, and blanks.

lsblk -f returns:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                         
├─sda1 ext4            69fe002a-8d2a-4297-ac0b-272c60c019ce /
├─sda2                                                      
└─sda5 swap            82575a1c-ca49-4060-b860-d078ad7b54d6 [SWAP]
sdb                                                         
└─sdb1 ext4   31GBEXT4 e19d4f79-0600-42c4-8159-77a844544c09 /media/greg/31GBEXT4
sr0
```

`cat /dev/sr0` returns:

```
cat: /dev/sr0: No medium found
```

So I tried `lshw` and got this:

```
*-scsi
     physical id: 2
     logical name: scsi0
     capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVD RW AW-G540A
         vendor: SONY
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: 1.W0
         serial: [
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

And then there's this:

```
$ mkdir ~/dvd | sudo mount /dev/sr0 ~/dvd
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

I'm pretty much grasping at straws at this point. So, what now?

Update on info: I can locate it in Disks with no problem, but it shows no media when I have a DVD in the drive. I have already cleaned the lens, but that was never an issue as it worked fine before I installed Lubuntu 16.04

Results of `dmesg --level=err,warn`

```
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F8060 000024 (v02 PTLTD )
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x000000007F6D7E92 00008C (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x000000007F6DFC04 0000F4 (v03 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000007F6D9217 006979 (v02 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x000000007F6E2FC0 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x000000007F6E2FC0 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000007F6DFCF8 000068 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  0000005A)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x000000007F6DFD60 000038 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  0000005A)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000007F6DFD98 00003C (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  0000005A)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 0x000000007F6DFDD4 000176 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  01000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: TMOR 0x000000007F6DFF4A 000026 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  00000003)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000007F6DFF70 000068 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BOOT 0x000000007F6DFFD8 000028 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007F6D90FA 00011D (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007F6D8FD7 000123 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007F6D8506 000287 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007F6D8452 0000B4 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007F6D7F1E 000534 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BIOS bug: multiple APIC/MADT found, using 0
[    0.000000] ACPI: If "acpi_apic_instance=2" works better, notify linux-acpi@vger.kernel.org
[    0.016170] ACPI: 6 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.084000] core: PEBS disabled due to CPU errata
[    0.104013] PCCT header not found.
[    0.119640] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.119652] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88007C230800 00021D (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.120304] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.120315] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88007C238000 0004B7 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.121286] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.121296] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88007CBE2E00 0000E4 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.121854] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.121863] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88007C0ED480 000092 (v01 Sony   VAIO     20070718 PTL  20050624)
[    0.332102] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State >[\_S1_] (20150930/hwxface-580)
[    0.332110] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State >[\_S2_] (20150930/hwxface-580)
[    0.409139] pci 0000:00:1e.0: bridge has subordinate 09 but max busn 0c
[    0.410509] ACPI: Enabled 4 GPEs in block 00 to 1F
[    0.463911] pci 0000:00:1f.0: BAR 13: [io  size 0x0080] has bogus alignment
[    1.568935] ACPI: Invalid active0 threshold
[    9.388844] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001028-0x000000000000102F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000000107F (\PMIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    9.388865] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000000000011B0-0x00000000000011BF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011BB (\GPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    9.388875] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011BB (\GPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    9.388884] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   10.293226]  excluding 0xfc200000-0xfc20ffff
[   11.188633] ath5k 0000:06:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   82.003914] ath5k: ath5k_hw_get_isr: ISR: 0x00000400 IMR: 0x00000000
[  416.905530] perf interrupt took too long (2520 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[  866.322544] perf interrupt took too long (5003 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
[ 6254.003446] ath5k: ath5k_hw_get_isr: ISR: 0x00000080 IMR: 0x00000000
[ 8775.772141] ath5k: ath5k_hw_get_isr: ISR: 0x00040001 IMR: 0x00000000
[11894.003569] ath5k: ath5k_hw_get_isr: ISR: 0x00000400 IMR: 0x00000000
```

`cdrecord --checkdrive`

    `Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
    Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
    Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
    Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
    Version        : 5
    Response Format: 2
    Capabilities   : 
    Vendor_info    : 'SONY    '
    Identification : 'DVD RW AW-G540A '
    Revision       : '1.W0'
    Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
    wodim: Cannot load media with this drive!
    wodim: Try to load media by hand.
    Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
    Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
    Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96R RAW/R96R`

Did it again --> `cdrecord --checkdrive`

`Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.02a06 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 1995-2016 Joerg Schilling
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.36
Using libscg version 'schily-0.9'.
No target specified, trying to find one...
Using dev=0,0,0.
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'SONY    '
Identifikation : 'DVD RW AW-G540A '
Revision       : '1.W0'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM.
cdrecord: Cannot load media with this drive!
cdrecord: Try to load media by hand.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96R RAW/R96R
cdrecord: Warning: Cannot read drive buffer.
cdrecord: Warning: The DMA speed test has been skipped.`

...and `cdrecord --toc`

`Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.02a06 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 1995-2016 Joerg Schilling
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.36
Using libscg version 'schily-0.9'.
No target specified, trying to find one...
Using dev=0,0,0.
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'SONY    '
Identifikation : 'DVD RW AW-G540A '
Revision       : '1.W0'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM.
cdrecord: Cannot load media with this drive!
cdrecord: Try to load media by hand.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96R RAW/R96R
cdrecord: Warning: Cannot read drive buffer.
cdrecord: Warning: The DMA speed test has been skipped.
cdrecord: Cannot load media with this drive!
cdrecord: Try to load media by hand.
cdrecord: Cannot load media.`

Comment: Try running `dmesg` just after inserting a disc, to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: Okay, dmesg returns a long, long list of things I don't completely understand. Such a long list, that I can't scroll to the top in fact. What, exactly, am I looking for and is there a way to trim down the information to make the results more relevant?

Comment: Focus on the bottom, the newest messages, immediately after inserting a disc. If it helps, run `dmesg -w` and watch for new messages as you insert the disc.

Comment: Edit your post to include large output, please. Use code formatting the way I have done while editing your post.

Comment: Well, I'm throwing in the towel. It seems to be a kernel issue and well beyond my capabilities. I'm going to try installing another Ubuntu distro to see if it's specific to the distro. If that doesn't work, I'll install an older, not-so-flashy distro such as Puppy Linux, which my DVD drive worked fine on. Thank you sincerely for your time and help.

Comment: Don't throw in the towel. The drive is recognized by lshw, a kernel issue should make the drive invisible to lshw. Install `cdrecord` by `add-apt-repository ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools`, followed by `apt update` and `apt install cdrecord mkisofs`. Now put a plain audio cd into the drive and issue `cdrecord --checkdrive` and `cdrecord --toc` in the terminal. Results?

Comment: Okay @emk2203 , I tried your suggestion. Definitely seems like a driver problem to me (though it's really a wild guess based off of limited knowledge). I updated the posting to reflect the results.

Comment: The drive is ancient - 2007 or so. `cdrecord` would use the generic driver for it. It is correctly recognized. Did you install Ubuntu from it? Maybe it was on its last legs, and the strain from the installation has finally worn it out. That a 10-year old drive doesn't recognize media is very common, it's the usual symptom for a dead drive. To exclude any influence of Ubuntu, try booting a live cd - anything - with it. If this doesn't work, the drive is toast.

Comment: A million thanks for all the effort in hunting my problem down. I've kept trying, but only to see it work once, then stop working. I think maybe this dog's got no more fight in it. It's just really strange how it went from perfectly fine to nothing at all after an OS change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your system does find the drive and identify it properly as well, as a Sony DVD RW [AW-G540A.](https://www.cnet.com/products/sony-nec-optiarc-aw-g540a-dvdrw-r-dl-dvd-ram-drive-ide/specs/) Your output provided indicates that the difficulty is in reading from the drive which the system is convinced is empty as you mentioned. The root cause is likely a failed laser (since you've cleaned the lens). The device if it's repairable at all isn't worth the cost to repair. I recommend replacement of either the drive or the entire laptop (if the budget can handle it) considering the age.

Answer (score 0):

Command line `wodim` worked for me when nothing else would:

`$ wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0 ~/Downloads/turnkey-lxc-14.2-jessie-amd64.iso 
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'PLDS    '
Identification : 'DVD+-RW DH-16A6S'
Revision       : 'YD11'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
[...snip...]
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... input buffer ready.
Performing OPC...
Starting new track at sector: 0
Track 01:  241 of  241 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf  99%]  33.3x.
Track 01: Total bytes read/written: 252706816/252706816 (123392 sectors).
Writing  time:   68.873s
Average write speed  25.5x.
Min drive buffer fill was 99%
Fixating...
Fixating time:   17.636s
BURN-Free was never needed.
wodim: fifo had 3981 puts and 3981 gets.
wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 2893 times full, min fill was 95%.`

Courtesy of @bohoomil https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=143209

Answer (score -1):

just did from the part - "Don't throw in the towel"
i have Optiarc DVD RW AD-7530B (NX02)

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. there were 3 packages so i did: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
4. `sudo apt install cdrecord mkisofs`
5. restart

thats all, worked for me, made my day, thanks

Comment: I tried the cdrecord mkisofs... It didn't work. There some errors, but I really couldn't understand them.